# How to find the mean of the given column (some have ranges, other don't) in the data frame in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to find the mean of the given column in the data frame in Python (shown in the image). Some of them have ranges (i.e. 2-3 and 3-4), while other don't (i.e. 1 and 4).

Text version of the column in the dataframe:

```
lst = ["1", "2-3", "3-4", "4"]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df
1      
2-3      
3-4      
4
```

I tried using the below function, but it doesn't work for the ones that don't have ranges.

```
# a function to split the range and take the mean
def split_mean(x):
  # split before and after the hyphen (-)
  split_num = x.split("-")
  mean = (float(split_num[0])+float(split_num[1]))/2
  return mean
```

Edit:
Had to replace the NULL values for the bottom function to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function like this:

```
def split_mean(x):
  # split before and after the hyphen (-)
  split_num = x.split("-")
  if len(split_num) == 2:
     return (float(split_num[0])+float(split_num[1]))/2
  else:
     return float(x)
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the comment!

However, I'm getting an error where it says..

"float' object has no attribute 'split'"

I tried casting x.split("-") to string, but that didn't' work either.

Comment: Nvm I figured it out... it had NULL values so I just replaced them and it worked!! Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you use instead:

```
df[0].str.split('-').transform(lambda x: mean(map(int,x)))
```

you will get the output:

```
0    1.0
1    2.5
2    3.5
3    4.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```